# Fixing the document structure created with hyperref

Tags: hyperref, bookmarks

I am new to Latex, tentatively using it to prepare a complicated industrial document (laboratory test report). This document contains numerous test groups, and I have found convenient , for both the writer and the reader, to number the section of the test results of each group (and the tables and figures) with  the group number. I have managed to find a way that suits my need. However, when I use a starred version of the chapters, the resulting structure of the .pdf document is altered, in a way that on the attached sample, the chapter "test results" is shown as a branch of section 1 and not on the same level as other chapters... Is there a way to correct this behavior? Thanks.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, oneside,11pt, english]{report} % Mode production
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % UTF-8 encoding for code editing
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % Usual fonts
\usepackage{tgheros,textcomp}% Fonts
\usepackage{lastpage} % Handling last page numbering 
\usepackage{hyperref} %enabling hyper references

% --[SECTION NUMBERING FIRST PAGES]---------------------------------
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}
\renewcommand{\thetable}{\Alph{table}}
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{\Alph{figure}}
%  --[END SECTION NUMBERING FIRST PAGES]---------------------------------
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}%selecting default font (clone of helvetica)

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents %  [CREATING TABLE OF CONTENTS]---

\chapter*{Summary of test results}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Summary of test results}
A table.

\chapter*{Test specimen}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Test specimen}
\section{section 1}
Some text.
\section{Section 2}
Some text.

 \chapter*{Test results}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Test results}

%-[BEGIN ASSOCIATE TABLE AND FIGURE NR TO SECTION NR]----
\makeatletter 
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{\ifnum \c@section>\z@ \thesection.\fi 
\@arabic\c@figure} 
\@addtoreset{figure}{section} \makeatother 
\makeatletter 
\renewcommand{\thetable}{\ifnum \c@section>\z@ \thesection.\fi 
\@arabic\c@table} 
\@addtoreset{table}{section} \makeatother 
%-[END ASSOCIATE TABLE AND FIGURE NR TO SECTION NR]-----


\renewcommand{\thetable}{\thesection.\arabic{table}}
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{\thesection.\arabic{figure}}

\setcounter{section}{-1} % setting counter to assign  number 0 to group 0 
\setcounter{figure}{-1} % setting counter to assign  number 0 to figures of group 0
\setcounter{table}{-1} % setting counter to assign  number 0 to figures group 0


\section{Group 0}
\subsection{Visual examination} 
No defect observed. 
\subsection{Examination of dimensions and mass} 
The results meet the requirements stated on the drawings.
\subsection{Magnetic permeability}
The results meet the requirements. 
\subsection{Mating and un-mating forces }
The results meet the requirements.

%----------------          
\section {Group 1} 
%----------------

some text
\subsection{Visual examination}  
some text
\subsection{Measurement of insulation resistance} 
some text
\end{document}
```

Comment: The problem lies with you resetting the `\setcounter{section}{-1}`. Can you please post a sample of what you want to achieve?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is fixed with the addition of the [`bookmark` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/bookmark)

```
\usepackage{bookmark}% http://ctan.org/pkg/bookmark
```

to your document preamble (no load order restriction with [`hyperref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref), so before or after):

[image: Correct bookmark organization with the inclusion of bookmark package]

Comment: Thanks a lot... I had been trying to understand the problem for a while....

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way is to use `\chapter` and avoid printing "Chapter n"; however, this needs also fixing the table of contents:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\let\@makechapterhead\@makeschapterhead
\patchcmd\l@chapter{\begingroup}{\begingroup\let\numberline\@gobble}{}{}
\makeatother
```

Then the simple `\chapter{Summary of test results}`, without adding `\addcontentsline` will do.

The package `bookmark` is recommended anyway. However, loading it and leaving your code unchanged will produce warnings and possible incorrect links:

```
pdfTeX warning (ext4): destination with the same identifier 
(name{section.0.1}) has been already used, duplicate ignored
<to be read again> 
                   \relax 
l.79 \section {Group 1}
```

This doesn't happen with the patches I suggest.

The line `\let\@makechapterhead\@makeschapterhead` makes `\chapter` behave, as  far as printing is concerned, like its unnumbered sibling (but the chapter number will be stepped nevertheless).

The `\patchcmd` line tells LaTeX to ignore the `\numberline{n}` bit in the ToC entry (`n` stands for the actual chapter number) by exploiting the fact that the entry is typeset inside a group: so in that group we redefine `\numberline` to be the same as `\@gobble` that makes its argument disappear.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I had also noticed the warning, but had not understood how to get rid of it. I must admit I do not understand everything in your code either, but I am going to study. Your code brings the additional benefit of keeping the chapters numbered, and this is preferred in such a document.....